# Photoshop: color profile keeps changing to ProPhoto RGB instead of sRGB

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-profile

The last few weeks I'm having trouble with wrong color profiles attached to my exported JPG images.

I've always have my color space set as sRGB but somehow, somewhere something has changed where my images now have the ProPhoto RGB. Which sucks because this mainly becomes apparent when uploaded.

Am I missing some preferences that are not set correctly?

Comment: Probably this is because your setting is to use whatever the image you had opened has as profile and the camera is set to use ProPhoto

Answer (score 1):

Maker sure you have the correct settings.Check **Edit > Color Settings..**:

[image]